# What is the Qt way of doing a random switch function that never uses the same case twice in a row?

Tags: c++, qt, random, switch-statement

I'm assuming the code should look something like this:

```
QString Boat::programming()
{
    int rand = ???; 
    switch (rand) {
    case 1:
        return function1();
    case 2:
        return function2();
    case 3:
        return function3();
    case 4:
        return function4();
    case 5:
        return function5();
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

Requirements:

- When I call the function a second or third time, `rand` can not use the same value it had last time, or the time before.
- Must use Qt's framework.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Just remember the old value in an extra variable and keep rolling until you hit a different one.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yeah... I should probably delete this. A Softball programming question if I ever saw one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a dupe for this anyways, but do as you please. (I don't have the time to look for it right know.)

Comment: Build an array of size 5 with function pointers to all 5 functions and perform a random shuffle on it. Keep a counter indicating the current position. Once you reach the end, reset the counter and re-shuffle the array. Not very random but if that's what you need to implement, that's how you'd do it.

Comment: @IInspectable if the re-shuffle moves the last value to the start, you'll get the same value twice in a row.

Comment: @Chungzuwalla: That's correct. I read the specification differently, though, as in: Must not execute one of the functions more than once, until the entire set of functions has been called.

Answer (score 1):

I assume '???' is the Qt way to get a random number in the range you want.  Just wrap '???' in another function that stores the last 2 values it returned...

```
int myrand()
{
    static int pp = -1, ppp = -1;
    int p;
    do { p = ???; } while (p == pp || p == ppp);
    ppp = pp; pp = p;
    return p;
}

QString Boat::programming()
{
    int rand = myrand();
    ...
```